# PHP INSERT INTO Table OR Table Variable Not Functional and No Error

Tags: php, sql-server

Good Afternoon,
I have the following mock up script of my code. It appears that the following will not work with PHP and returns no error, but the query is sent to the SQL Server which I can see in a profiler trace. PHP Returns no response.

Ideas?

Will work with PHP:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

Will not work with PHP:

```
DROP TABLE #TMP1
SELECT 50 AS INT INTO #TMP1
SELECT * FROM #TMP1
```

Will not work with PHP:

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE 
(
ID INT
)

INSERT INTO @TABLE (ID)
SELECT 40

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
```

Will not work with PHP:

```
<?php  
$databaseName = "DB" ;
$serverName = "3424.34.234.3";   
$uid = "sdfsf";     
$pwd = "Jsdfsf";     


$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>$uid,                              
                         "PWD"=>$pwd ,                              
                         "Database"=>$databaseName);   


/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */    
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName , $connectionInfo); 



$tsql = "
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE 
(
ID INT
)
INSERT INTO @TABLE (ID)
SELECT 40

SELECT * FROM @TABLE
";  



//EXEC PLAYER_LOOKUP  '$result';

/* Execute the query. */    

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);  


    //Working Query
/* Iterate through the result set printing a row of data upon each iteration.    BR=."\n" */

  while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_ARRAY($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
      { 

    echo $row;


    }}  

/* Free statement and connection resources. */    
sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);    
sqlsrv_close( $conn);    

?>
```

Comment: if you run your "$tsql" directly using SQL server management studio, it will work?

Comment: Correct it will run in SSMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you have to do is to call SET NOCOUNT ON at the beginning of the stored procedure. This will prevent the "rows affected" messages to be sent to the client and be mistaken for the output of the procedure. Also you may have set it before a SELECT * INTO Statement.